# VB.net 2005 Type mismatch with datatable to crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

on my .xsd file where I create the datatable for use in my Crystal Report (buit in with Visual Studio 2005), I have included a column (which is datatatype = 'Byte') that is supposed to hold the image for my crystal report.

However, there is always an error thrown at where I've typed COMMENT1, saying that the file is being used by another process. The file I am accessing is a mapped drive to our server.

when I try to ignore the error and press on continue, the report does show up..but without the image it was supposed to be with.

below is my complete syntax

```
    Dim x As New Reporter
    x.MdiParent = Magulang

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("EmpNo")
    dt.Columns.Add("FullName")
    dt.Columns.Add("Project")
    dt.Columns.Add("SSS")
    dt.Columns.Add("TIN")
    dt.Columns.Add("EmergencyPerson")
    dt.Columns.Add("EmergencyAddress")
    dt.Columns.Add("EmergencyContact")
    dt.Columns.Add("PicNya", System.Type.[GetType]("System.Byte[]"))

    Dim middleinitial As String = MiddleName.Text.Substring(0, 1)


   Dim fs As FileStream
    Dim br As BinaryReader


    If File.Exists(PicPath.Text) Then

     'COMMENT1 : there is error here, saying that file is used by another process
    fs = New FileStream(PicPath.Text, FileMode.Open)

    Else

        fs = New FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "NoPhoto.jpg", FileMode.Open)
    End If
    br = New BinaryReader(fs)
    Dim imgbyte As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length) {}
    imgbyte = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32((fs.Length)))

    MsgBox(imgbyte.ToString)
    dt.Rows.Add(EmpID.Text, FirstName.Text & " " & middleinitial & ". " & LastName.Text, Project.Text, SSS.Text, TIN.Text, EmergencyContact.Text, "", EmergencyContactNo.Text, imgbyte)

    br.Close()
    fs.Close()


    Dim rptdoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptdoc = New HRISID1

    rptdoc.SetDataSource(dt)
    x.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptdoc
    ProgressForm.Hide()

    x.Show()
```

What can I do to resolve COMMENT1? if resolved, will the image finally output in my crystal report? Am I on the right track, if I wanted to output images on my computer?

Comment: All of this is to create an ID for our employees.

Answer (score 0):

For now, we have resolved to instead pass each Data into a seperate form, then use the PRINTFORM object included with the VB Powerpacks. This is to make sure the image is also printed.

I can't help but feel this isn't the proper solution though, so if anyone can still contribute it's very much welcome.